# How To Get Steam Under 10 $ Game Json Api

Tags: json, laravel, api, steam

I need games under $10 on Steam. How should an inquiry be made for this?
[api link here](https://store.steampowered.com/search/results?maxprice=20&cc=tr&l=turkish&json=1)
In the link here, I can only fetch games under $10 as json, but there is no information such as game id prices.
I need these. Thank you

```
    $steamUnder20 = Http::get("https://store.steampowered.com/search/results?maxprice=20&cc=tr&l=turkish&json=1");
    $resultUnder = $steamUnder20->json();

Result :

    "desc": "",
    "items": [
    {
    "name": "Black Desert",
    "logo": "https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/582660/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1658233501"
    },
    {
    "name": "Slime Rancher",
    "logo": "https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/433340/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1651003375"
    },
```

Comment: You should add some details of what you've tried first, what errors you're getting etc. Guides for asking questions are here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: The link I shared is the url I already tried. However, there is no apid and price information of the game in this url. I need these. Not clear enough?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the API to search for games under $20, but then only wanting the ones that are under $10 in the result? Also, what does the documentation say about search results?  Is there a way to request specific information from the API etc? If you're using a non-published API call (i.e., one that is meant only for the steam store), I recommend going via the official APIs as they're probably more complete

Answer (score 1):

Steam offers an endpoint called appdetails that allows you to fetch a whole lot information about one or multiple comma-separated game IDs specified in the `appids` parameter:

```
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=1,2,3
```

According to the inofficial documentation by RJackson in the Team Fortess wiki you can specify the values you need in the `filter` parameter, otherwise the response will include all basic details: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#appdetails

In your case I suggest iterating through your response and parsing the gameID from the logo URL and using them collectively for the appdetails endpoint to fetch all the information.

Additionally, you can also use the `cc` parameter to specify a currency and the `l` parameter to localise the response. These parameters are not documented in the documentation by RJackson.